# What is the best way of uploading 1,600,000 rows of data into mysql database?

Tags: mysql, php, database

This might sound dumb but yeah i need a effective way of doing this. 
Am using php at the moment and man it is slow.

Any pointers please.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anytime I have to insert massive amounts of data, I try to use "LOAD DATA INFILE":

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

The bottleneck could also be the indexing of the data.  I would recommend disabling indexing prior to running the load data infile and then enabling it afterward.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I like HediSQL http://www.heidisql.com/. I have moved databases with over a million rows using it. There is an import an export feature that works quite well. It's a great mysql client and makes working with mysql much easier than using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Yeah have been using heidisql too. But this problem required to be solved using web based interface as we are programming an admin ui for a transportation quote system. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is deleting any indexes before you do the insert.  Once you have inserted everything create the indexes again.

MySql actually has a really good article on this and other methods.  Take a look at it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html).